# Unable to load monaco editor in SAPUI5 typescript project

Tags: typescript, sapui5, monaco-editor

We are trying to load monaco editor, a third party library in sapui5 typescript project, but it's not loading

Here is the project git repo https://github.com/dhrubajyoti2006/ui5_ts_thirdParty_Monaco

getting this console error,
[image]

we can see code editor loaded, but with corrupted output.